# How to get all matching intents

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is there a way to get  all matching intents, not only one result with the biggest score, for example right now I get 

 `"result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "my test",
    "action": "",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {},
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "",
      "webhookUsed": "false",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "intentName": "intentName"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "test",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "test"
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 0.9200000166893005
  },`

I want to return all intents when the score is not high to allow users to choose their intent.

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: @LeonNicholls I want to return all intents when the score is not high to allow users to choose their intent.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to return all matching intents.

Given the use case described in the comments, you can just set your fallback intent to return a set of suggestions to the user. The fallback intent is triggered when none of the intents have a sufficiently high score to match.